# How do I view Ant scripts that eclipse uses?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am having a bit of trouble building my project with Ant. I wanted to take a look at the Ant scripts that eclipse uses to build my project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select *Project » Properties » Builders* to see what runs when Eclipse builds your project.

Comment: That doesn't actually let you view the XML does it?

Comment: The actual xml is in the .project file in your project. It's not ant, but a description of which incremental project builders will be run to build the project. Note that some of the builders could be ant scripts or external programs.

Comment: True - in the novice case there are probably only have built-in (non-Ant) builders, but in general you might also have your own custom builders that are Ant tasks.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think eclipse uses ant scripts to build your project by default. However, eclipse can generate ant scripts for you. This can be done by right click project > export > General > Ant buildfiles. Make sure you uncheck the 'use eclipse compiler' if you want the build file to be usable from outside of eclipse.

Comment: This must have been the answer!

Answer (score 3):

No ant scripts are used building in the workspace, however, exporting your projects does use ant scripts.  You can generate such scripts by right click on the MANIFEST.MF or feature.xml and PDE Tools -> Create Ant Build File.

The exact contents of the generated ant scripts will depend on the options selected for export, so there may be some differences.